What is wrong with my neural network runtime?
Having started working with Neural Network in WM 14.0 I encounter the following strange problem. The code
L0 = LinearLayer["Input" -> {5}, "Output" -> "Real"]

generates messages:
*General::interr2: An unknown internal error occurred. Consult Internal`$LastInternalFailure for potential information. (3 times)
General::stop: Further output of General::interr2 will be suppressed during this calculation.
General::nnlibload1: The function "mxlMXGetVersion", required by the neural network runtime, cannot be loaded from "D:\Mathematica_Folder\SystemFiles\Components\MXNetLink\LibraryResources\Windows-x86-64\MXNetLink.dll".
General::nnlibunavail: The neural network runtime is unavailable.
End::noctx: No previous context defined. (2 times)*
Repeated execution of this code finishes as needed, initialization (L1 = NetInitialize[L0]) also finishes well, but the code:
L1[{0.7, 2.6, 0.2, 0.7, 0.5}]

fails with message:
LinearLayer::nnlibunavail: The neural network runtime is unavailable.
OS: Windows 11. As I see, the reason is a software trouble (OS or WM), not a code error

Hint: The issue you're encountering seems to be related to the availability and loading of the neural network runtime, specifically the MXNet library required by Wolfram Mathematica. This can happen due to several reasons such as missing or corrupted files, improper installation, or compatibility issues with the OS.
Here is a minimal example to ensure that the code you are using is syntactically correct and should work under normal circumstance.
(* Load the necessary Neural Networks package *)
Needs["NeuralNetworks`"]

(* Define the linear layer *)
L0 = LinearLayer["Input" -> {5}, "Output" -> "Real"]

(* Initialize the network *)
L1 = NetInitialize[L0]

(* Execute the network on some input *)
output = L1[{0.7, 2.6, 0.2, 0.7, 0.5}]


Thank you. The code became working after software re-installing. Sorry to disturb you

Thanks, if  my answer is convincing you may need to accept it
